# TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, knn

I am trying to make movie recommendation system, want to sort movies based on genres and in this I want to use csr matrix but when I do that, I get this error. I don't know how to solve it. Below is my code for the same.

```
!pip install requests fuzzywuzzy pandas pyjstat numpy plotly matplotlib seaborn geopy google folium pandas googlemaps

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df_movies = pd.read_csv('/content/movies.csv')
df_ratings = pd.read_csv('/content/movies.csv')

df_movies.head(10)
df_ratings.head()

movies_user = df_movies.pivot(index = None, columns = 'movieId', values='genres').fillna(0)
#print(movies_user) -> here i'm getting the desired result  

mat_movies_user = csr_matrix(movies_user.values) 
#error in the above line: TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric ='cosine',algorithm ='brute', n_neighbors=20)
model_knn.fit(mat_movies_user)
```

Comment: Tell us about `movies_user.values`.  `shape`, `dtype`, sample elements?

Comment: `df_movies.shape`: (9742, 3)                                                                   
 `df_movies.dtypes`:                                                    
 movieId ->> int64, 
title  ->>    object,
genres  ->>   object,
dtype: object

Comment: `df_movies_user = df_movies.pivot(index = None, columns = 'movieId', values='genres').fillna(0)`    
`print(df_movies_user.values)
`   :  [['Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy' 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 'Adventure|Children|Fantasy' 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 'Comedy|Romance' ... 0 0 0]
 ............
 [0 0 0 ... 'Drama' 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 'Action|Animation' 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 'Comedy']]

Comment: Who or what told you could use a dataframe like this?

Comment: I don't know much about this things but took help from some youtube videos and some blogs. The below is the code from that blog from which I took referene.         
`from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix`
# pivot ratings into movie features
`df_movie_features = df_ratings.pivot(
    index='movieId',
    columns='userId',
    values='rating'
).fillna(0)`
# convert dataframe of movie features to scipy sparse matrix
`mat_movie_features = csr_matrix(df_movie_features.values)`